# Can I use a bonding terminal on ground wire between ufer rod and panel

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

Long story short, I need to replace an electrical panel.  In my the new panel the grounding bar is in a different location than the current panel.  The ground wire from the Ufer rod will not reach to the new ground bar.  Am I allowed to use a bonding terminal to "splice" a longer ground wire, or does it need to be one continuous wire?

[image]

Comment: What make and model is the new panel?

Comment: The new panel is Siemens PW3040L1200CU

Comment: So the ground conductor will now reach to a point inside the panel, but not all the way to the ground  bar? Or does it not even reach to the panel?

Comment: It goes into the panel, just not all the way to the ground bar

Answer (score 2):

### There's an easier fix for this

Get a Siemens EC1GB82 ground bar kit and mount it to the bottom-most set of ground bar holes in your loadcenter cabinet, with the large lug down.  Then, you can simply terminate the annoyingly short ground wire to the bottom bar's large lug and call it a day.

This works because all the ground bars on a panel are electrically equivalent -- the cabinet connects them all together, by virtue of itself needing to be grounded.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'm not seeing any other ground bar holes in the panel.  I'm editing the post to add a photo of the panel.

Comment: @NickRomanyshyn -- that's a bit peculiar...

Answer (score 0):

You can also splice the wire to extend the wire as long as it is the same size and type and you a non-reversible type splice. (crimp style)